# JQuery not running

Tags: jquery

The titles a tad vague, but i cant seem to find the right description of the problem. Basically for some reason my JQuery is not running, seemingly it is due to jquery not being enabled, buuut the link is there, before my script call too. [Here is the general idea](http://jsbin.com/abokey/2/edit)

However when i do run the script locally i get an error in mozilla and the jquery doesnt run, nothing happens on hover:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined @index.js:3
```

As far as I can tell everything is perfect, however it seems like the JQuery library is not being registered, heres my head:

```
<head>
    <title>Javascript Tetris</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "index.css"><!--add the css-->
    <script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!--add jquery library-->
    <script src = "index.js"></script><!--add javascript file-->
</head>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use :

```
 <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

you missed `https`

Comment: He didn't miss it. You don't need it if you are running on a web server. It'll automatically add it in relative to the protocol of the document.

Comment: nope this is right, i completely didnt take into consideration that i was running this locally without server, its a fresh linux install no apache yet. Its always the small things we miss, thanks man

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!--add jquery library-->
```

// is trying to pull from your local file system. That'll work fine on a server, but on your local machine you gotta specify http or https.

Answer (score 1):

Just check your sytax before you post here

you missing http:

```
<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He didn't miss it. You don't need it if you are running on a web server. It'll automatically add it in relative to the protocol of the document.

Answer (score 1):

**if you are using live link the use this**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**or if u are using from your local copy then download these file and put in
 your app folder and give the reference like this.**

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify full path with http -  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js